# Using a class library which has a Xamarin.iOS in a MAUI Project

Tags: ios, xamarin, native, maui

I develop an ios app with MAUI and there is a barcode scanner device for iphone. To use this device, I need to add a dll which uses Xamarin.iOS.
When I add this dll to the main project, it requeires Xamarin.iOS.dll and when I add Xamarin.iOS.dll to the project, I get the following error

[image]

[image]

NSData has a conflict and unfortunately I cannot use Xamarin.iOS's NSData. like Xamarin.iOS.Foundation.NSData

So then as an alternative, I created another class library (this is not a maui class library). And I added Xamarin.iOS and the device's DLL into this project and I can successfully compile.

But when I add this class library to the maui app project, I get the following error while building

```
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.2.1007/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(3,3):
Error: clang++ exited with code 1:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr", referenced from:
     -u command line option
     (maybe you meant: _xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_ref_IntPtr_exception,
 _xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_IntPtr_int_exception , 
 _xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_int_int_int_int_exception , 
 _xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_Int64_Int64_Int64_Int64_exception , 
  _xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_UIntPtr_IntPtr_IntPtr_exception , 
  _xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_UInt64_Int64_Int64_exception , 
  _xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_IntPtr_IntPtr_IntPtr_exception ,
  _xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_UInt32_int_int_exception , 
   _xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_IntPtr_IntPtr_IntPtr_IntPtr_exception )
  "_xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_IntPtr_UInt32", referenced from:
     -u command line option
  "_xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_IntPtr_UInt64", referenced from:
     -u command line option
  "_xamarin_Int (TestMauiApp)
```

And beside that, when I add the device's DLL into the maui project and select "Link All" from Link behavior, the project can be compiled and I deploy to my phone but when I open the app, I see the screenshot and then the app crashes. Even there is no single code in the project. (just boilerplate)

Unfortunately device manufacturer does not support MAUI now.
https://asreader.com/products/asr-023xd/
The supported ones: objective C, swift, cordova and xamarin.
I am not sure whether I can embed the objective-c/swift lib into my project.

If I can solve this problem with Xamarin, it would be great. Otherwise I have to use Xamarin.Forms instead of MAUI for this app.

Comment: Short story: you can't. If you can get hold of the sources, you can change the Target Framework to net6.0-ios and it should™️ just work

Comment: @Cheesebaron thank you for the reply. Actually they also share source code of the project which was written in Xamarin.IOS. I did not see any "Target Framework" in that project. Can I somehow implement it? Actually I tried to copy the codes but the MAUI does not have BaseType attribute, that's why I could not use it.  Like that: [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface AsReaderRFIDDeviceDelegate

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a Xamarin.iOS Binding project. A Xamarin.iOS Binding project is meant to expose Objective-C code to Xamarin's C# codebase and is not forward-compatible with .NET for iOS and MAUI.

These projects need to be converted to the newer .NET for iOS Binding project type first. This needs to be done manually at the moment. One way to do this is to create a "iOS Binding Project" like this:

- `dotnet new iosbinding -o MyBinding` (replace MyBinding with whatever you want the name of your binding to be).
- This will create a new .NET for iOS binding project (which should also be compatible with MAUI).
- Then bring over the `ApiDefinition.cs`, `StructsAndEnums.cs`, `.a` and/or `.framework` files and directories, any native references, other settings and resources from the original Xamarin.iOS binding to the new binding project. (Make sure the SmartLink, ForceLoad etc. settings for the NativeReferences match those of the original binding project)
- Build the new binding project. The result should now be usable in a .NET for iOS or MAUI project.

**Note**: If you reference the resulting DLL instead of the binding
project itself, make sure the generated `BindingName.resources`
folder is in the same directory